# How to use feathersjs to declare internal services without restful?

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

FeathersJS provides a good way to create restful API on top of nodejs. But I have not figured out a way to create a service internally used in my app without restful.

Below is a sample of code:

```
const myService = {
  find(params [, callback]) {},
  get(id, params [, callback]) {},
  create(data, params [, callback]) {},
  update(id, data, params [, callback]) {},
  patch(id, data, params [, callback]) {},
  remove(id, params [, callback]) {},
  setup(app, path) {}
}

app.use('/my-service', myService);
```

In other services, they can use `app.service('/my-service')` to reference that service instance. But it also exposes a restful API on `myService` instance. How can I create a service without exposing? I just want to use that service inside my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [disallow](https://feathers-plus.github.io/v1/feathers-hooks-common/#disallow) hook with the `external` (or `rest` or `socketio`) parameter to disable external access:

```
const { disallow } = require('feathers-hooks-common');
const myService = {
  async find(params) {},
  async get(id, params) {},
  async create(data, params) {},
  async update(id, data, params) {},
  async patch(id, data, params) {},
  async remove(id, params) {},
  setup(app, path) {}
}

app.use('/my-service', myService);

app.service('my-service').hooks({
  before: disallow('external')
});
```

Comment: When I am doing this , I got this error "Error: 'before' is not a valid hook method"

Comment: @Daff is there any way to find out whether the service is called internally or externally?

Comment: Yes, for external calls `params.provider` will be set to the transport it has been called with.

Comment: For anyone trying to do this on the latest versions of Feathers you can find some guidance here: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/688